# Good Game Dev Engine?

Tags: ide

I'm new to game dev, and would like to know a good engine/program to code games with. I tried C#, and generally enjoyed the experience, but found that without something like MonoGame or XNA Studio, it was too slow and CPU-reliant for game dev. i also tried Unity, but found that I don't enjoy using a graphical interface, and prefer just coding with only a bit of graphical interface, like with Visual Studio. I have also tried Java, and quite enjoyed the experience, so that might work. My question is: what is a good way to make a game with mostly writing code? Any help would be appreciated! :D

Comment: This question is very much opinion based and if I recall correctly they don't like that on these websites and might lock out the question from comments soon. That said you sound a lot like me in your pursuit of gamedev. I'd say MonoGame, XNA (frameworks for C#) and LibGDX (framework for Java) are essential tools to start out creating games. Without them as you have said, it takes much longer and you are basically spending weeks re-creating something that is already in libgdx etc. It depends on what your target platforms are and the language you most comfortable.You seem to be on the right path

Comment: If you like scene graph based engines jmonkey engine is excellent and based on java which is probably the fastest you'll get without going to c++ (and it'll be faster than c++ done poorly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Java you could uses LWJGL, libgdx, or SFML (with java bindings)
but as for C#, MonoGame/XNA are kinda your best options for premade engines.

You can always get OpenGL/GLEW in either Java or C# and write your own engine from scratch. If you're not familiar with certain design concepts and theory it may take (a lot) longer, but you'll know your engine inside out.

Best of luck on your game!

Comment: Thanks! I'l try Monogame, I've heard it's like an open-source XNA, so it sounds like my thing. :D

Answer (score 1):

Normally would comment this but app won't let me so I'll provide as an answer.

There is absolutely nothing in unity that says you have to use their GUI beyond browsing your files and importing assets. You can work almost exclusively in Visual Studio in C# and still take advantage of all short cuts and pre-built functionality of Unity, not to mention the built in support for cross platform deployment.

I personally do not use Unity so this is not the Pov of a fanboy, but in the past I have used it as described. My personal choice is UE4 but if you don't like gui and don't want to work in C++ (mostly managed by engine) it's probably not for you.